# $M\otimes_A N = M\otimes_{A/a} N $?

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $a$ an ideal. Let $M$ and $N$ be $A$-modules.

Now suppose $a\subset Ann(M)\cap Ann(N)$. I'm hoping that $M\otimes_A N = M\otimes_{A/a} N$. Is it true?

Comment: Literarlly the same question has been asked two days ago here. I'm too lazy to enter it into the search, but you should do that (or should have done before asking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. For any $A/\mathfrak a$-module $P$, $A$-bilinear maps $M\times N \to P$ are clearly the same thing as $A/\mathfrak a$-bilinear maps $M\times N\to P$, since $M$ and $N$ are killed by $\mathfrak a$.

By the universal property of the tensor product and by the Yoneda lemma, it follows that there is a canonical isomorphism $M\otimes_A N \simeq M \otimes_{A/\mathfrak a} N$.